# Add view to EntityFramework 6 not work?

Tags: c#, sql, entity-framework, view

I have the following view:

```
SET ANSI_NULLS ON
GO

SET QUOTED_IDENTIFIER ON
GO



ALTER VIEW [dbo].[RateAverageValueView] WITH SCHEMABINDING
AS
    SELECT 
        Id = NEWID(),
        AverageRateValue = AVG(Value) 
    FROM dbo.Rate


GO
```

But I can't add it to EF model(edmx file).
I know it should have a Primary Key column, so I added `Id = NEWID()`, but it doesn't work.
What's problem?

In Visual Studio's warning section the following error is listed:
**Warning:**

```
Error 6013: The table/view 'YoutubeLinks.dbo.RateAverageValueView' does not have a primary key defined and no valid primary key could be inferred. This table/view has been excluded. To use the entity, you will need to review your schema, add the correct keys, and uncomment it.
```

Comment: Why not write a scalar valued function?

Comment: I just find the reason of problem for more experience.

Comment: What doesn't work? Please be specific. Do you get any error message?

Comment: See warning section

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I changed view to following:

```
SET ANSI_NULLS ON
GO

SET QUOTED_IDENTIFIER ON
GO



ALTER VIEW [dbo].[RateAverageValueView] WITH SCHEMABINDING
AS
    SELECT 
        Id = 1,
        AverageRateValue = AVG(Value) 
    FROM dbo.Rate


GO
```

The problem solved :)

Answer (score 0):

Use `SCHEMABINDING` when you create the view, which will allow a PK to be added, as described in this previous answer: [How do you add a primary key to a sql view? - Or alternate way to link views to LINQ-2-Entities](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1821877/how-do-you-add-a-primary-key-to-a-sql-view-or-alternate-way-to-link-views-to)